# SQL Server Management Studio not showing complete selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used following code to select data for `Item_Id =1` and between dates `2010-06-16` and `2010-06-17`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [System_SiteAzure].[dbo].[Values]
WHERE ([Timestamp] BETWEEN '2010-06-16' AND '2010-06-17')
  AND ([Item_Id] = 1)
```

However, I realised that there are some missing rows which means the selected data is not complete. I am new to SQL and I am wondering what could be the potential reasons why this is happening? Thanks

For instance, this is a part of the data I get after selecting using the aforementioned code:

```
      Id    Timestamp               Values  Item_Id
36409897    2010-06-16 16:00:57.870 40      1
36409898    2010-06-16 16:01:00.993 39.5    1
36410345    2010-06-16 16:10:07.207 39      1
36410346    2010-06-16 16:10:10.333 38.5    1
36410731    2010-06-16 16:19:29.267 38      1
36410732    2010-06-16 16:19:32.393 37.5    1
36414061    2010-06-16 17:41:00.487 37.5    1
36414062    2010-06-16 17:41:03.613 39.5    1
36414065    2010-06-16 17:41:06.740 40.5    1
36414070    2010-06-16 17:41:09.863 41      1
36414071    2010-06-16 17:41:12.990 41.5    1
36414232    2010-06-16 17:45:26.893 42      1
36414233    2010-06-16 17:45:30.017 42.5    1
```

whereas for the same time interval, complete data should look like this:

```
Timestamp   Values
16:00:01    47.5
16:00:04    48
16:02:03    47.5
16:02:06    47
16:03:37    46.5
16:03:40    46
16:05:27    45.5
16:05:30    45
16:07:36    44.5
16:07:39    44
16:09:35    43.5
16:09:38    43
16:11:59    42.5
16:12:03    42
16:15:42    41.5
16:15:45    41
16:18:19    40.5
16:18:22    40
16:19:47    39.5
16:19:50    42
16:19:54    43
16:19:57    44
16:20:00    44.5
16:20:03    45
16:22:24    44.5
16:22:27    44
16:23:46    43.5
16:23:49    43
16:26:04    42.5
16:26:08    42
16:30:10    41.5
16:30:14    41
16:33:03    40.5
16:33:06    40
16:36:12    39.5
16:36:15    39
16:40:41    38.5
16:40:45    38
16:43:09    38.5
16:43:12    42
16:43:15    43
16:43:18    43.5
16:43:21    44
16:46:43    43.5
16:46:46    43
16:49:13    42.5
16:49:16    42
16:53:00    41.5
16:53:03    41
16:55:46    40.5
16:55:49    40
16:58:45    39.5
16:58:48    39
17:03:00    38.5
17:03:03    38
17:06:08    37.5
17:06:11    37
17:06:34    36.5
17:06:37    36
17:12:26    35.5
17:12:29    35
17:16:54    34.5
17:16:57    34
17:23:26    33.5
17:23:30    33
17:25:01    33
17:25:04    34
17:25:07    36
17:25:10    41.5
17:25:14    43
17:25:17    44
17:25:20    44.5
17:25:23    45
17:25:52    45.5
17:25:55    46
17:27:39    46.5
17:27:42    47
17:28:04    46.5
17:28:07    46
17:30:09    45.5
17:30:12    44.5
17:30:25    45
17:30:28    45.5
17:32:31    45
17:32:34    44.5
17:35:27    44
17:35:30    43.5
17:37:39    44
17:37:42    44.5
17:37:46    45
17:37:49    45.5
17:41:37    45
17:41:40    44.5
17:44:11    44
17:44:14    43.5
17:46:41    43
```

Can it be that I'd potentially missed out some functions?

Comment: Your question makes no sense without example of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using rowversion  as timestamp is getting deprecated.

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable2 (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, VerCol rowversion) ;
```

by default sql management studio will show you 1000 rows only.
check the sql it is "select top 1000" . Remove top 1000.
But I see you put whole sql there.
So the problem is in query.
check if timestamp is of type timestamp and it has data like this

```
RowID   TimeStamp   SmallDateTime   DateTime
1   AAAAAAAAB9E=

CREATE TABLE MyTestTable(RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TimeStamp] TIMESTAMP, [SmallDateTime] SMALLDATETIME,
[DateTime]  DATETIME)
INSERT INTO MyTestTable([SmallDateTime],[DateTime])VALUES(GETDATE(), GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM MyTestTable


ROWVERSION and TIMESTAMP Overview
Summary information:

Syntax  ROWVERSION  Available since SQL Server 2005
TIMESTAMP   Deprecated 
Generated Numbers   Unique within a database
Storage Size    8 bytes
Internal Representation BINARY(8)   For non-nullable
VARBINARY(8)    For nullable
Number of Columns Allowed   One per table
```

Comment: From the example, it looks like the timestamp column is a datetime, not a rowversion.